# Building a Ranking Model for Junior Golf

Tags: predictive-models, econometrics, ranking, elo

So, I'm trying to figure out the best way to build a model for Junior Golf Rankings.  The best system out there currently uses a Sagarin type methodology that compares head-to-head records of connected players along with the stroke differential between players--however this model doesn't use enough events in the world of junior golf (they use 250 of about 3,000 that are out there)

For example, in a tournament with 100 players, the winner is 99-0, 2nd place is 98-1, tied for 18th with 3 other players 79-17-3, etc.  That creates the player's record.  Then there is some sort of comparison made by which a player that finishes 2nd, by way of losing a sudden death playoff with the winner, but is 6 strokes clear of 3rd--this person is treated differently than a player who comes in 2nd, 6 strokes behind the winner and only 1 stroke clear of a large group of players tied for 3rd.

I'm trying to figure out where to go to find someone to help me build this model.  I have all of the results that would be necessary to plug into the model.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question, but maybe you should explain junior golf and the tournament a bit better. This may help you to get a larger group of people to understand your question/problem.

Comment: Have you looked yet at the Bradley-Terry model?

Comment: Sextus Empiricus: There are thousands of tournaments and thousands of junior golfers.  I'm looking to be pointed in the direction where I can have a model built to determine rankings based upon results in all of these events.  This is not something I have the ability to do myself but something in which I am wanting to engage someone for assistance.